# Passing array from controller to view - Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make Quiz application. I have more than 600 questions in various categories such as jp, sn, ei etc. Now I want to show the questions and options to users from various categories in randomly. But getting error. Would someone help me to do right. I tried something like this - 
In my Controller.php

```
public function index()
{
    $jp = DB::table('e_questions')->take(2)->inRandomOrder()->where('dichotomy', '=', 'JP')->get();
    $sn = DB::table('e_questions')->take(2)->inRandomOrder()->where('dichotomy', '=', 'SN')->get();
    $ei = DB::table('e_questions')->take(2)->inRandomOrder()->where('dichotomy', '=', 'EI')->get();
    $tf = DB::table('e_questions')->take(2)->inRandomOrder()->where('dichotomy', '=', 'TF')->get();
    $equestions = array("$jp","$sn","$ei","$tf");
    //dd($equestions);

  return view('question.english.index', compact('equestions'));
}
```

And in my view index.blade.php

```
             @foreach($equestions as $equestion)
                 <p>{{ $equestion->question }}</p>
                 <p>{{ $equestion->option1 }}</p>
                 <p>{{ $equestion->option2 }}</p>
             @endforeach
```

Comment: I removed this.

Comment: try like this $equestions = array_merge($jp,$sn,$ei,$tf);
and please show the error which you facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, create an array like this:

```
$equestions = [$jp, $sn, $ei, $tf];
```

Then iterate over the data:

```
@foreach($equestions as $equestionType)
    @foreach($equestionType as $equestion)
        <p>{{ $equestion->question }}</p>
        <p>{{ $equestion->option1 }}</p>
        <p>{{ $equestion->option2 }}</p>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. It is what I expected.

Comment: 60k Congrats. :)